# Logout handler Silex

Tags: security, service, logout, silex, provider

i would like to change the status of a USER after logout. But i have no idea how to make it.

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider());
$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
        'chat' => array(
            'pattern'=>'/chat',
            'anonymous'=>false,
            //login_path: before authorisation  Check_path: path to check the date of the user
            'form'=>array('login_path'=>'/login','check_path' => '/chat/login_check'),
            //should realizise the logout
            'logout'=>array('logout_path'=>'/chat/logout','target_url'=>'/logout'),
            'users'=> $app->share(function() use ($app){
                return new \resources\controller\UserProvider($app['db']);
            })
        )
);
```

It seems to be no session any more. I already the with the

```
'invalidate_session'=>false
```

and

```
'invalidate_session'=>true
```

option. It dont work.

Thank for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can add logout handler

```
$app->extend('security.firewall', function($firewall, $app) {
    static $initialized = false;
    if ($initialized) return $firewall;
    $initialized = true;

    // logout handlers
    $app['security.authentication_listener.administration.logout']->addHandler(
        new \My\Logout\LogoutHandler()
    );

    return $firewall;
});
```

LogoutHandler should implement `LogoutHandlerInterface`

```
class LogoutHandler implements LogoutHandlerInterface
{
    public function logout(Request $request, Response $response, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for yout help, but i dont understand it.I pit it in my code but i have no effect....i feel like i sitting on my head...should i need the  'target_url' and should i set a logout route??? Sorry for all this questions and thank for your help